# Parental control: Allow a single app ( restrict all other apps) in Android tab

Tags: android, parental-control, kiosk

Is there any way to restrict all other app except one in Android tabs ( if possible kindly mention how to do in Huwaei tabs). As the online schooling going on, need to allow only Zoom ( or Google Meet) during the online study time.

Comment: While I'm shocked to read Zoom and Google Meet in context of "parental control" *this way* (i.e. not protecting them from those data collectors) – the term you're looking for is "kiosk mode". One app offering this (I have not tried it myself, so please check for yourself) would be [Boomerang](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nationaledtech.Boomerang) – coming itself with some trackers, though (AdMob, Google Analytics).

Comment: I will check it and will update the experience.